# How does Enumerable.Sum bind to an array type?

Tags: c#, linq

I am confused about how LINQ sum method works.
So, we have for example an `int` array and int structure doesn't have a `sum` method.

But then when we include LINQ, magically it does.
How is the sum method added to the structure so we can invoke `arr.sum()` ? Through some kind of inheritance or how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How is the sum method added to the structure

Most collection classes implement `IEnumerable<T>`. `Sum`, as in your example, is an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for `IEnumerable<T>`.

Extension methods are essentially static classes with static methods, where each methods first value is added the `this` keyword. This way, the compiler recognizes it as an extension method to be applied to the type.

Here is [`Enumerable.Sum`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,d0619109936422da) in it's simplest form declared on `IEnumerable<decimal>`:

```
public static decimal Sum(this IEnumerable<decimal> source) 
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    decimal sum = 0;
    foreach (decimal v in source) sum += v;
    return sum;
}
```

There are many overloads of `Sum`, each with a different type of an integral and floating point type. They can be found [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,17ae8142727f08ee) if you're interested.
All extension methods are applied on the given type. Given that an array implements `IEnumerable<T>`, it also gets these methods as an add on.

Comment: so you are telling me that any type that matches an Extension Method arguments, can use that Ext Method like it is part of it (using . operator)?

Comment: @CuriousGuy That's what i'm saying, yes. You can try it out yourself. Create an extension method for `int`, or `string`, and see the magic happen.

Comment: @CuriousGuy he's not only saying it, it's also true.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) It is kinda weird though (the "magic", not the explanation)

Comment: @CuriousGuy It is syntactic sugar that the compiler applies. You get this type of things often. If you look, for example, at C# 6.0 features, you'll see most of them are exactly that.

Comment: @CuriousGuy it's not so much something that extension methods allow for, it's exactly what extension methods are, no more and no less